# Get details about SQL updated records

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I need suggestions about a logic. There is an update query in application like below

```sql
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET FLAG = CASE 
                WHEN FLAG = 'IP' THEN 'P' 
                WHEN FLAG = 'IH' THEN 'H' 
                WHEN FLAG = 'IM' THEN 'M' 
              END 
WHERE ADJUSTMENT_ID IN (SELECT Query )
```

This update is executed from a Java function which returns `void`.

Now I have a requirement to get details of updated records too (few columns from table TABLE) and return a `LIST` from function instead of `void`.

Running SELECT first then updating records in loop is not an option due to performance reasons. Records are updated with a single UPDATE statement because its supposed to run faster.

What would be options for me keeping comparable performance? Should I go with a stored procedure?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `flag` contains any other value than `IP`, `IH` or `IM` the column will be updated to `null`. If there is a possibility that the `where` clause selects rows with other values, you should add an `else flag` to the `case` statement

Comment: thanks, where clause in query takes care of that. I missed to mention that. This condition is there in WHERE clause `AND FLAG IN ('IP','IH','IM')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ... FROM FINAL TABLE (UPDATE ....)
```

will do the job. As it is a single SQL statement the performance will aslo be good.

See also 
http://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogid=278&blogaid=422

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works from command prompt. In Java, With `PreparedStatement` , we use `executeUpdate()`for `SQL UPDATE` and for `SQL SELECT` we use `executeQuery()` so which one would be used here? I guess it would be `executeQuery()` and I am not sure if you are a Java guy or not.

Comment: `executeQuery()` works for me when I execute `UPDATE` with `FINAL TABLE`